# Why is the absolute value of a equal to -a when a < 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, absolute-value

I'm doing some math work involving proofs, and one of the definitions is:

|a| = -a when a < 0

Isn't the absolute value of a, positive a no matter what a is in the beginning? Am I looking at this wrong? Could use an explanation.

Comment: Remember $-(-1) = 1$.

Comment: If $a$ is negative and you want to make it positive, you multiply it by $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

If $a < 0$ then $-a > 0$, so $-a$ is positive.

The point is that if $a = -2$ for instance, then $\lvert -2 \vert = -(-2) = 2.$

Answer (score 1):

"Isn't the absolute value of $a$, positive $a$ no matter what $a$ is in the beginning?"

Yes.  $-a $ is a positive number.

"Am I looking at this wrong?" Yes.  $-a$ is a positive number.

"Could use an explanation?"

$a < 0$.  So $a$ is negative.  Which means $-a > 0$ and $-a$ is positive.

Also $a = -|a|$ (an equation with 2 negative values).   So if you negate both sides you get $-a = -(-|a|) = |a|$.

Or a specific example.  Let a = -25.  Then $|a| = 25$.  $-a = -(-25) = 25$.  SO $|a| = 25 = -a$.

Moral: when we say a "negative times a negative is a positive" we *mean* it. $-a$ is *positive* if $a$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

$|a|$ is always positive, but if $a$ is negative at the beginning, the absolute value is *equal* to $-a$, because negating a negative number results in a positive. This is merely a a property of $a$, not of $|a|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0$ you can consider it as $-|a|$ since $|a|$ is absolute value(like unsigned value).

So $a=-|a|$, and $|a|=-a$

Example: $a=-1$, $|a|=1=-(-1)=-a$

Answer (score 0):

$\renewcommand\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$The general idea is this: For any nonzero real number $a$, we can decompose it as $s \cdot t$, where $s = +1$ or $-1$ is a sign, and $t > 0$ is a positive number. I'll call these $s = \sgn(a)$ and $t = |a|$. (Here $\sgn$ is called the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).)

If $a$ is positive, then put $\sgn(a) = +1$ and $|a| = a$. Then it's clear that $|a|$ is positive, and $\sgn(a) \cdot |a| = +1 \cdot a = 1$.

If $a$ is negative, then put $\sgn(a) = -1$ and $\color{red}{|a| = -a}$. Then $|a|$ is positive ($a$ is negative, so $-a$ is positive), and $\sgn(a) \cdot |a| = -1 \cdot -a = a$.

(If $a = 0$ then $\sgn(a)$ is undefined, but $|a| = 0$.)